# Переход с Gradle 5.0 на 7.0

Tags: gradle

Есть маленький кусочек build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
repositories {
    mavenCentral() 
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5' 
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar') 
}
task printDependencies {
    doLast {
        configurations.compile.each { println it.name } 
        }    
    }
```

как нужно написать строку "configurations.compile.each { println it.name }" в таске, чтобы она работала в седьмом Gradle?